# Is is possible to have a slickgrid inside another slickgrid?

Tags: slickgrid

Is it possible to have a slickgrid inside another slickgrid (without modal ) ?
As an example, using Magic TCG and the example http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-grouping-checkbox-row-select.html .

I want a slickgrid were I can order the collections and when I select the collection, it will open another slickgrid in the same window, with the cards.

On the "main-grid" will have the columns related to collections (e.g. collection name, # of cards in that collection, etc) and on "child-grid" will have the columns related to the cards (e.g. card name, card cost, card info, etc).

**EDIT**: I forgot to tell I replicated the code from the first grid and then tried to called it but got this error :

> SlickGrid requires a valid container, #myGrid2 does not exist in the DOM.

I'm calling it like this :

```
<div id="myGrid" style="width:100%;height:500px;">
    <div id="myGrid2" style="width:100%;height:500px;">

    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible or do I need to use modal ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed possible, I have a slick-combo control (not publicly released) that provides a multi-column combo inside a cell using a dynamically created Slickgrid.

It looks like you want a side-by-side grid, not a grid-within-a-cell. Could you provide more information around how you want the screen visually to look (a diagram would be good)

Comment: Hello Ben !
I really wanted a grid within a grid ! Something like this [link](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/img/subgrid-grid.png)
I know jqGrid does it, but since Im working around with slickgrid I wanted to know the possibility to do this !

Comment: Ah. Well, that's going to be very difficult, if not impossible. Slickgrid has a fixed row height. There is a plugin that gets around that (http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example16-row-detail.html) and you'd need to put a hook into the plugin to create a new grid when opening the row detail.

Comment: Hey Ben! I tried that, but somehow, it adds a empty row with the panelrow size on the top and if I open 3 , it will hide the others. Im trying to get this one working mixing with the grouping example but seems a little hard for now

Comment: yeah that plugin is not really fully integrated into the grid. I'm leaving it to the owners to maintain and support it!

Comment: Thank you Ben for all the help! :)